# Utilizando jstl y servlet para consulta a db

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Estoy en un proyecto java web application y estoy intentando hacer consultas a la bd MySQL y mostrarlas en un jsp sin usar código java. Vi esta solución en una respuesta de una pregunta vieja, pero al ejecutarlo no me muestra ningún registro.
Tengo lo siguiente:

Pedidos.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Pedidos</title>
        <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="Actividad.jsp">Actividad</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="Pedidos.jsp">Pedidos</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>IdRepartidor</th>
                    <th>IdPedido</th>
                    <th>Hora Inicio</th>
                    <th>Hora Fin</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${repartos}" var="reparto">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${reparto.id}</td>
                        <td>${reparto.idRepartidor}</td>
                        <td>${reparto.idPedido}</td>
                        <td>${reparto.horaInicio}</td>
                        <td>${reparto.horaFin}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

ConsultaPedidosServlet.java

```
@WebServlet(name = "ConsultaPedidosServlet", urlPatterns = {"/ConsultaPedidosServlet"})
public class ConsultaPedidosServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        Consulta cons; 
        try {
            cons = new Consulta("repartos");
            ResultSet rs = cons.recuperar("idRepartidor = 11");
            List<Repartos> repartos = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()){
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                int idRep = rs.getInt("idRepartidor");
                int idPed = rs.getInt("idPedido");

                Repartos rep = new Repartos(id, idRep, idPed);
                repartos.add(rep);
            }
            request.setAttribute("repartos", repartos);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Pedidos.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConsultaPedidosServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }   
}
```

---

Consulta.java

```
public class Consulta {

    private final String tabla;
    private final Connection cnx;

    public Consulta(String tabla) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        this.tabla = tabla;
        this.cnx = Conexion.obtener();
    }

    public ResultSet recuperar(String condicion) throws SQLException{
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            PreparedStatement consulta = cnx.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + this.tabla + " WHERE " + condicion);
            rs = consulta.executeQuery();
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
        throw new SQLException(ex);
        }
        return rs;
    }
}
```

---

Conexion.java

```
public class Conexion {

    private static Connection cnx = null;


    public static Connection obtener() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
       if (cnx == null) {
          try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/deliverytrackingdb", "root", "root");
          } catch (SQLException ex) {
             System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
             System.out.println(ex.getMessage());   
          }
       }
       return cnx;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la URL que consultas? Asímismo, ¿has hecho debug respectivo para ver que `repartos` contiene al menos 1 valor y no es una lista vacía?

Comment: A que te referís con la URL que consulto? Estoy intentando ver que tiene reparto, pero puse un syso(rep.toString()), pero en consola no sale nada, estoy viendo como solucionar eso.

Comment: No es igual que contactes a "http://localhost:8080/tuAplicacion/Permisos.jsp" que "http://localhost:8080/tuAplicacion/ConsultaPedidosServlet".